# How can I always start app in the main Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, startup

I have 3 activities A, B and C. What A does, is that it redirects the user to either activity B or C according to a Preference value (which the user can switch as he likes). 
Now, my problem is, for this to work then activity A needs to be the first activity to run EVERY time the user opens my app, otherwise the selection isn't made.

So if the user is in activity B and presses the home button and then afterwards opens my app I want the app to run activity A, and not B as usually happens.

I've tried in the manifest file to set android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" in activity A, but this doesn't help. It still just jumps directly to activity B.

I also read that perhaps calling finish() in onStop() in activity B and C could be a solution, but this is bad since entering the Preferences activity (through the OptionsMenu in activity B and C) will call OnStop() on the activity, thereby closing the activity so when I want to return from the Preferences activity (by pressing back) my app closes (since there's nowhere to return too).

I could of course make a boolean and try to check if I'm going to the Preference activity and only call finish() when I'm not going there, but that hardly seems like the right way to do it.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` on activities B and C will get it done?

Answer (score 3):

Use this android:launchMode="singleInstance" in your manifest file inside those activities that you want to open only once. If you open that activity and then press home button, and then again open your app, it does not resume your previously opened activity. It opens parent activity. Realy, it works for me guys while  I am building broadcast receiver app. Try it

Answer (score 0):

put this code in onPause method (override it) at activity B

```
finish();
```

Comment: Calling finish() in onPause() in activity B will do the exact same thing as if I do it in onStop(). All in all, activity B is closed. So if I go to Preferences activity (from activity B), then i can't return, so that's a no go :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to finish your activity when you press the Home key? Try to add this code in B and C activities:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {
      if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
      {
           finish();
           return true;
      }

      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

EDIT: You can also try to finish() your activities in the onResume method. Here, you can finish B or C, and start A...

Comment: That might actually work. Because now B and C is only finish()'ed when the home button is pressed and NOT when you visit the Preference Activity :) I'm gonna try this when I get home :)

Comment: Often, problems can be solved by reformulating them in a different way :P Let me know if you can solve this problem ;)

Comment: and what if someone gets an incoming call? or using the notification bar to get away from your app instead?

Comment: I just tested your solution a bit more, putting a log call between if(...) and finish();. The logging message is never shown, so I guess something is wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Bind & unbind to a service in B, C and the Preference activities' onStart & onStop.

Register and unRegister a BroadcastReceiever in B & C's onStart & onStop.

In the service's onDestroy, broadcast the custom broadcast intent that B & C are registered for. On receiving this broadcast, finish the activity.

Whilst B, C or Preference Activity are on screen, the service is Bound. When none of these are on screen (user presses the home button or (importantly) they open another application from the notification bar), the service is unbound and destroyed - triggering a Broadcast message that will finish any instances of B & C in the back stack.

Since B's onStart is called before Preference's onStop (if pressing back from the Preference screen), the Service stays alive and nothing is finished.

Comment: I seem to understand the idea, but could you perhaps post a link where I can see exactly what you mean. Is it a specific broadcast intent you're thinking of or? :)

Answer (score 0):

In the `manifest` file you should set your main activity like this:

```
<activity android:name=".A">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This should always open `A` when you launch your application. It's not enough to just set the `clearTaskOnLaunch` attribute (I'm not particularly sure if it's correct either).

`B` and `C` should be defined like this in your `manifest` file:

```
<activity android:name=".B"> 
</activity>
<activity android:name=".C"> 
</activity>
```

Neither of them should have the same `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` attributes as `A` as they are not the first activity you want to show.

Comment: Activity A will be launched when the Application doesn't already exist - which it might be if you press Home and then re-enter the app, in which case, the previous activity is resumed (could be B or C), which is what he wants to avoid.

Comment: The OP can call this.finish() when the Home Button is clicked upon. I think another user has posted the code for that on this question.